# How do I configure IE7 to download filetype instead of opening in browser

Tags: internet-explorer, download, watir, browser-automation

I have written a watir script that downloads files. One of the files it downloads has a .dcf extension. Months ago, on my machine, I changed a setting somewhere so that .dcf files prompt for download ("Do you want to open or save this file?") instead of opening in the browser. This is the behavior that I desire.  I am using XP Pro/IE7.

I'm now setting up a dedicated test machine, but cannot seem to find the configuration option that I did on my machine - which was so easy to find that I didn't make note of it.  All of the solutions that I am finding now are either about changing the download itself or modifying the registry. I am looking for something from the client perspective at the browser/IE level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[tloach](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14092/tloach)'s link provided direction towards the answer I needed:

1. I needed to open a windows explorer window and select **Folder Options...** from the **Tools** menu.
2. I needed to go to the **File Types** tab and locate the extension for which I wanted to change behavior.
3. I needed to have the **Advanced** button for the file type - it isn't always there.
4. The **Confirm open after download** checkbox needs to be ***checked*** (not cleared)
5. There need to be Actions - there aren't always.  I found that one called **edit** and another called **open** were enough.  I tied them to notepad (C:\WINDOWS\system32\NOTEPAD.EXE %1).  I also needed to ***check*** the **Use DDE** checkbox and fill  in *NOTEPAD* for **Application:** and *System* for **Topic:**

Hopefully this will help others.  It will likely help me the next time.

Answer (score 1):

instructions here:
http://www.mydigitallife.info/2007/06/15/disable-automatic-opening-or-saving-of-downloads-re-enable-always-ask-before-check-box/

Comment: I've followed those directions and unchecked the 'Confirm open after download' in the File Type dialog.  The file still opens in a browser window.

I also checked the machine that is working the way that I want, and the 'Confirm open after download' is still checked there.

Answer (score 0):

For PHP, try using these headers:

header("Content-Type: application/force-download");

header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");

header("Content-Type: application/download");

header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".basename($filename).";");

Naturally you can make use of the same headers in whatever language you are using.

Comment: You get it wrong (as I did when first read the question). He is asking about IE7, not really a programing question.

Comment: Not really, I just missed the 'F' before the 'or' in the beginning of the answer. But I totally understood it.

Comment: Eduardo, isn't content-type header supposed to used just once?

Comment: Yes, sorry, that's what I actually meant, "try using *one* of these headers" :)
My guess would be that the last one would be used though, as they are read one-by-one...

Comment: Oh, and yes, I misunderstood the question. It really was a "userspace" issue :P